# Storing values for each iteration Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, while-loop, sum

The code down below goes through the `Vals` function and it assorts through the `Numbers` value and adds up all the sums after the sorting. I am trying to append the `SUM` values to the `T_SUM` to store the values of each `SUM` for each sort.

```
Vals= np.arange(start=60, stop=105, step=5)
Numbers = np.array([123.6,       130 ,       150,        110.3748,     111.6992976,
 102.3165566,   97.81462811 , 89.50038472 , 96.48141473 , 90.49956702, 65])
T_Sum = np.array([])
p= 0 

while len(Vals) != p:
    Numbers= np.where(Numbers >= Vals[p],Numbers ,0 )
    p = p + 1
    SUM = np.sum(Numbers)
    T_Sum = np.concatenate((T_Sum, SUM))

print(T_Sum)
```

Comment: So what's the question or problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use masked arrays to mask values you desire and then sum them up all in one line:

```
T_Sum = np.ma.masked_array(np.repeat(Numbers[None,:],Vals.size,0),mask=[Numbers<Vals[:,None]]).sum(-1).data
```

output:

```
array([1167.28664878, 1167.28664878, 1102.28664878, 1102.28664878,
       1102.28664878, 1102.28664878, 1012.78626406,  922.28669704,
        727.9906542 ])
```

Comment: Hello there I made another issue for a tpic like this if you take a look at it I would appreciate it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66466529/formatting-and-summing-up-numbers-with-arrays-numpy-python

Answer (score 1):

This should do the same thing:

```
Vals= np.arange(start=60, stop=105, step=5)
Numbers = np.array([123.6,       130 ,       150,        110.3748,     111.6992976,
 102.3165566,   97.81462811 , 89.50038472 , 96.48141473 , 90.49956702, 65])
T_sum = np.empty(len(Vals))
count = 0

for i in Vals:
    Numbers= np.where(Numbers >= Vals[p],Numbers ,0 )
    SUM = np.sum(Numbers)
    T_sum[count] = SUM
    count += 1
```