# Formatting and summing up numbers with arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to calculate the `T_Sum` value so that for the values that are greater than the `Vals` values in `Numbers` it will just add up to the `Vals` values for that element. For example, the first element of `Vals` is 60 and all the values within `Numbers` are greater than 60 (11 in total), so the result will be 60 * 11. If the `Vals` value is 105 there are 5 elements that are greater than 105 so the result will be 525. How can I do this without a for loop?

```
Vals = np.arange(start=60, stop=105, step=5)
Numbers = np.array([123.6, 130, 150, 110.3748, 111.6992976,
 102.3165566, 97.81462811, 89.50038472, 96.48141473, 90.49956702, 65])
```

My attempt

```
T_Sum = np.ma.masked_array(np.repeat(Numbers[None,:],Vals.size,0),mask=[Numbers<Vals[:,None]]).sum(-1).data
```

Expected Output

```
[660, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 810, 760, 600, 525]
```

Comment: 'there are 5 elements that are greater than 6' what do you mean by that?

Comment: It was supposed to be 60. I updated the issue.

Comment: Sorry about that i have updated it, i think it should be good now.

Comment: Yes fixed it sorry lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end value of `np.arange` must be greater than 105, because it's not end inclusive.

```
Vals = np.arange(60, 106, 5)
T_Sum = (Numbers[:,None] > Vals).sum(axis=0) * Vals
```

Answer (score -1):

The arrange method is not inclusive of the `stop` value, so your Vals actually ends at 100, not 105 like you seem to think ti does.

In any case, this will do what you want, just have to play with the start/stop values to get the final result you are looking for.

```
import numpy as np
Vals= np.arange(start=60, stop=105, step=5)
from collections import Counter
Numbers = np.array([123.6,       130 ,       150,        110.3748,     111.6992976,
 102.3165566,   97.81462811 , 89.50038472 , 96.48141473 , 90.49956702, 65])


output = []

for v in Vals:
    c = 0
    for n in Numbers:
        if n>v:
            c+=1
    print(f'There are {c}, values greater than {v}')
    output.append(c*v)

print(output)
```

Output

```
There are 11, values greater than 60
There are 10, values greater than 65
There are 10, values greater than 70
There are 10, values greater than 75
There are 10, values greater than 80
There are 10, values greater than 85
There are 9, values greater than 90
There are 8, values greater than 95
There are 6, values greater than 100
[660, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 810, 760, 600]
```

Comment: I am trying to use a numpy function to do that, since for lops arent optimized well and are slow, but thanks anyways.